# What rule governs the sequence 3, 9, 27, 30, 33?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

I recently had to complete an assessment for a job application which dealt with recognizing the patterns in number sequences and identifying what the next number in the sequence would be. One sequence which certainly stumped me was:

3, 9, 27, 30, 33

Now looking at it I believe the next number would be 51. I got that from there being a difference of 6 between 3 and 9, then a difference of 18 from 9 to 27, then a combined difference of 6 from 27 to 33. So the pattern, I think, is a difference of 6 (which can be done in one step or multiple) followed by a jump of 18. I now think to add 18 to the 33 to get the next number as 51. However I am not sure, and want to see what others think. I would be interested in all thoughts and opinions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: FWIW I searched this sequence on OEIS and found no results so I don't think this sequence has a rule.

Comment: If you divide everything by $3$ you get $1,3,9,10,11$ which [appears four times in OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C9%2C10%2C11)

Comment: The pattern is that the first five terms in the sequence are 3, 9, 27, 30, 33, and then all terms after that are zero. (This is meant to illustrate the subjectivity of this sort of question.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the only sensible answer to this (kind of) question in a job interview is "it depends". There is not enough information even to make a probable guess.

And any guess (for example, for the sequence $2,4,6,8, \ldots$) is only probable. Absent further information there are infinitely many ways to continue any finite sequence.

See [Is there a way of making "guess the next number in the sequence" rigorous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569815/is-there-a-way-of-making-guess-the-next-number-in-the-sequence-rigorous?rq=1) .

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the first two terms,
which are clearly observational errors,
each term is 3 more than their predecessor.

Comment: I like this, but not enough to upvote it.

Comment: At least you didn't downvote it, so I will upvote your comment.